# Snack shipped with computer products

Tags: hardware, software, market

I remember that there was a company in the US that packed candy or snacks as a bonus in the shipping box with their products. They were well-known for this practice. I'm pretty sure the snack was either [Moon Pies](https://moonpie.com/) or [Goo Goo Clusters](https://googoo.com/). I can't remember if the products were hardware or software or if it was a retailer of multiple products.

What company was this, what were the products and when was this done?

I've done some pretty thorough searching and wasn't able to find any mention of this.

<sub>This question was previewed [on meta](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1195/2057).</sub>

Comment: An interesting question, considering that Prusa (3D printers) is well known for including Haribo gummy bears in the product when shipped. As this is in retrocomputing, one would expect that your source predates Prusa by a substantial duration.

Comment: I can recall an optics company, and a vacuum equipment supplier that did that, but have no recollection of a computer hardware/software company doing so...

Comment: @fred_dot_u: And Atomic Filament includes Albanese gummy bears. These brought to mind the (incomplete) memory of the earlier instance in my question. Note that there may be a tie to Tennessee since both Moon Pies (Chattanooga) and Goo Goo Clusters (Nashville) are from there.

Comment: Thorlabs, which supplies fiber optic equipment, is known for shipping boxes of “lab snacks” with orders. But I think there’s a lot of companies the OP could potentially be referring to.

Comment: I don't know, but whenever I wanted a snack I went to Fry's and bought some hardware to go with it.

Comment: There was a Scandinavian CRT monitor supplier who used popcorn as packing material. This was in the 1990s, I think. Obviously, this was basic popcorn, without butter, toffee, or other flavourings.

Comment: @JohnDallman more recently [an online beer shop in France used to use edible, corn-based packing material](https://unepetitemousse.fr/blog/emballage-du-coffret-davril/)!

Comment: Cray Research may have shipped a crate of Leinenkugel's beer with one of their supercomputers. Unfortunately, did not manage to find a link to substantiate this.

Comment: So much for the trial run on Meta.